# Go build multiple/nested packages?

Tags: go

I just started writing Go today (so 0 experience), and wonder if Go supports any form of "building all source files" like what `mvn install` does.

My project structure is

```
src
  `-github.com
          `-myproject
               |- package1
               |     `- main.go
               `- package2
                     |- lib1_used_by_main.go
                     `- lib2_used_by_main.go
```

When I do

```
cd src/github.com/myproject
go build
```

this fails with `no buildable Go source files in src/github.com/myproject`, which is kind of right, because all source files are in subpackages.

Is there a command to build all subpackages, *without listing each of them explicitly*?

Comment: Any required packages are built as needed, you don't need to do anything. You only need to build main, as `go build` on a non-main package doesn't produce any artifacts.

Comment: I frequently need to do this so my autocomplete works in SublimeText.

Comment: @JimB This is incorrect. Building non-main packages builds source and places it in `go/pkg`. Anything (e.g. IDE) that relies on the `go/pkg` folder will benefit from being properly up to date. See my answer.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: no, it's correct. From the [`go build` docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies): `When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package, build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object, serving only as a check that the packages can be built.` If you want to save the build artifacts, you can use `go install` or `go build -i`.

Comment: @JimB Interesting... perhaps `margo` from GoSublime intercepts the results for the purpose of updating the autocompletion then? Either way, simply building my package after adding a new function (etc) updates my autocompletion.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After you `cd` to the base directory, use `go build ./...` Note that there are 3 periods as it is an ellipsis. This will recursively build all subdirectories. Of course you can always do `go build path/to/my/base/...` from wherever without needing to `cd` to the directory.

This is very useful for those who use an IDE that relies on the `go/pkg` directory, such as SublimeText3 with [GoSublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GoSublime). Making changes to a dependency package won't update the autocompletes until you build the package, which places it in the `go/pkg` directory.

My own projects are broken into a multiple package structure, so I frequently have to `go build ./...` to update my autocompletion.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work well with `vendor`, as it tries to build things in it too and fails with dependencies not found.  Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Is it giving you "can't find import...."? If that's the case, you need to `go get` each individual import it lists.

Comment: My solution to the vendor issue is simply to put my mains in ./cmd in different directories for each entrypoint. Then you can `go build ./cmd/...`

Comment: Where can I find the executable after running go build ./... ?

Comment: By default the executables aren't kept. From `go help build`: "When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package,
build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object,
serving only as a check that the packages can be built."

To get binaries, use the `-o` flag, point it to a directory where they will be placed.

Comment: Update: no more vendors :)