# How to build/install cross-compiled nested packages quickly?

Tags: go

I have a repository with a group of nested go packages organized as follows:

```
$GOPATH/src/
  - mypackage/common/utils.go
  - mypackage/app1/main.go
  - mypackage/app2/main.go
  ...
```

It compiles to a handful of binaries. For releasing, I'm cross-compiling for a multitude of platforms/archs (I deploy repeatedly with a different `GOOS` and `GOARCH`). I'm trying to write the compilation results to a directory of my choice, but I'm fighting with the toolchain.

I can:

1. Combine `GOBIN` and `go install` when compiling for my own architecture
    (i.e. *not* cross compiling):

   ```
   # build + output all binaries in /somedir/bin
   # this works great when compiling for my local architecture.
   GOBIN=/somedir/bin go install mypackage/app1 mypackage/app2 mypackage/app3
   ```

   But unfortunately, `GOBIN` conflicts with cross-compilation e.g:

   ```
   # Throws: "cannot install cross-compiled binaries when GOBIN is set"
   GOBIN=/somedir/bin GOARCH=amdm64 GOOS=darwin go install mypackage/app1 mypackage/app2
   ```
2. Use `go build` with `GOOS=X` and `GOARCH=Y` *for each subpackage*

   ```
   # cross compile one of the binaries
   cd /output/darwin-386-bin/ && \
   GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build mypackage/app1

   # but if given multiple binaries, there is no output. (as documented)
   GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build mypackage/app1 mypackage/app2
   ```

   When `go build` is given multiple packages, it no longer emits binaries -- it just checks that the code compiles. To emit *all the binaries*, it seems I have to run `go build` once for each subpackage, so it takes longer, esp when building with `-a`.

   Another possible issue with using `go build` like this, is that it's potentially mixing binaries and intermediary results across multiple architectures in the same workspace. But maybe that's just a matter of taste. Hopefully the toolchain keeps cached results separate for different architectures.

How is this handled in practice? Should I treat each subpackage as an individual package, despite their shared common code (would it then be safe to build them all in parallel)?

Related articles:

- go build vs go install: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/s8Csz3-7EXA  (Little info on cross-compilation, or multipackage setups)
- cross compile with go 1.5.: https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5  (does not specifically address multipackage / common code compilation. Also, the statement about having to recompile the standard library into /usr/local/go/pkg seems to no longer hold in 1.9.1, as far as I can tell)
- Go build multiple nested packages: [Go build multiple/nested packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399242/go-build-multiple-nested-packages) . ( The accepted answer, `go build ./...` behaves the same as passing multiple packages in a single build command, and therefore outputs no binaries. The thread  also does not cover cross compilation)

Answer (score 4):

What I'm about to suggest feels like a hack at best, but it might work for you if you're cross-compiling stuff in a container or an isolated build environment.

You can drop the GOBIN from the install command:

```
# I'm not on this platform, so this is a cross compile
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go install mypackage/app1 mypackage/app2
```

Assuming your package is in `$GOPATH/src/mypackage` the above command will install the two binaries to:

```
$GOPATH/bin/darwin_amd64/{app1, app2}
```

and the .a compile dependency files in:

```
$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64/mypackage/{app1,app2,common}
```

If you're running this in a for loop for all the platforms you plan on supporting, one nuisance with this process is that when you pass `GOOS=x GOARCH=y` matching your local architecture (i.e. not cross compiling), then the executables will be placed directly in `$GOPATH/bin/` and not `$GOPATH/bin/x_y/`.

(packages on the other hand always end up in `$GOPATH/pkg/x_y/`, cross compilation or not).

To determine your local architecture, you can follow steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669816/5556676 .

**Simulating `GOBIN=/foo/bin GOOS=x GOARCH=y go install mypackage/app{1,2,3}`**

Changing `$GOPATH` has little effect on where go install writes output. With some go commands, like `go get`, you tweak where packages are installed by adding a new component at the front of `$GOPATH`. But in go 1.9, `go install` will always copy binaries in the `bin/` folder that's a sibling of the `src/` which contains the packages to install.

Instead of using `GOBIN=/foo/bin`, you can pretend your source files are in `/foo/src/mypackage` (you may use a symlink), and then do `GOPATH=/foo GOOS=x GOARCH=y go install mypackage/app{1,2,3}`. This will put binaries in `/foo/bin`, because of the behavior I describe in the previous paragraph.

It's probably simpler to just grab the binaries from where you expect them to be though, than mucking with copying source trees around.

Comment: You shouldn't be installing anything into `GOROOT` (nor should you even have that variable set), did you mean `GOPATH`? You can also use `go build -o` if you want to place the output in a specific location.

Comment: Woops. I meant GOPATH. My container had GOPATH=/usr/local/go for some reason and it meddled things. Updated the answer. `go build -o` doesn't work with multiple subpackages, hence this question.